# php echo strings for multiple times with order

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $a = 11;
    $b = 22;
    $c = $a.'<br/>' $b .'<br/>';

    echo $c.'<br/>';
}
```

The result that I am having now is:

```
11
22
11
22
```

How can I make it become like the result below with the use of `$c`:

```
11
11
22
22
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use variables `$a` and `$b`. Simply do this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <3 ; $i++){ 
    $c = $i.$i;                                           
    echo $c;
}
```

**Update(1):** Based on your [**edited question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45535467/2), the solution would be like this:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < 6 ; $i++){ 
    $j = (int)($i/2); 
    $c = $j.$j;                                           
    echo $c . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: what if the $a =  ['a']; $b = ['b']; is it still possible to use this method ?

Comment: @John.J If you do `$a = ['a'];` and `$b = ['b'];` then `$a` and `$b` become array. Then what exactly you would want to do with these arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <3 ; $i++)
{ 
      $a = $i; 
      $b = $i; 
      $c = $a. $b;  
      echo $c; 
 }
```

This might work !!